# Can i run ubuntu from USB and save all information?

Tags: server, usb, lamp

Hello i want to install ubuntu to my USB and run it simle on each computer.

**I want to save all that i do.**

For example when i install localhost using my home computer, i go to work and run ubuntu from usb and access loclhost without any change , i want to work like this.

**how can i do that?**

Answer (score 2):

If you already have Ubuntu installed you can use the Startup Disk Creator which will install Ubuntu to a USB Stick. You'll need to make sure you first [download the ISO](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download) (If you want the best compatibility use a 32bit ISO). In the Startup Disk dialog you can sepcify how much space you want reserved for saving things like new software, documents, and settings. After doing so choose the Disk drive you want to use and the ISO then Make Startup Disk.

[image]

Everytime you plug in the USB select "Try Ubuntu" instead of install in the boot menu. That will drop you in a live session and your data will be saved to the extra space specified during the creation stage.

Comment: just uninstall ubiquity to avoid install option

Answer (score 0):

You can, just install it in a regular way. Connect your USB drive, insert the installation disk, and start the installation process. When you are asked to choose the drive to install, indicate your USB drive. The boot loader should also be installed on the same drive.
Make sure you have enough space on the USB drive.

To boot from USB, you'll need to tweak the order in which BIOS tries to load a system from detected devices on each machine.

Comment: I want to save all information on USB and i don't want to install ubuntu on computer , just from USB.

Now i'm on ubuntu, but i want to run in on my office computer

Comment: Yes, that is why you need to choose the USB disk as the destination for the installation. If you have an installation disk, you can try and boot from it. It will load Ubuntu, and you'll be able to connect to the Internet and ask further questions about the installation process.

Comment: Or, since you're on Ubuntu, Marco's answer is also a good option.